# Elixir/Phoenix LiveView documentation for conditional rendering attributes like :if

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I can't find it for the life of me. Does Phoenix have documentation for these attributes used with templates?
Sigh.

```
// where is documentation?
<div :if={length(@items) == 0}>
  0 result.
</div>
```

Comment: Hate to "me too" this, but it definitely should be more obvious. Glad you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some information here:
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#sigil_H/2-heex-extension-special-attributes